# Hilbert symbol (from Serre's A Course in Arithmetic p.38)

Tags: quadratic-forms

I'm reading Serre's A course in Arithmetic and there's one part in his proof that I don't understand. In his proof of Ch.4, n.2.2, Thm 6, he's trying to show that

$$(a_1,a_2)(a_3,a_4)(-1,a_3a_4)=-(-1,-1).$$

I could show this myself but I couldn't follow Serre's proof. Here's the part I don't understand:

$$(a_1,a_2)(a_3,a_4)(-1,a_3a_4)=(a_1,a_2)(-a_3,a_4)(-1,-1)$$

When I was trying to follow his proof, here's what I got.

\begin{align*}
(a_1,a_2)(a_3,a_4)(-1,a_3a_4)&=(a_1,a_2)(a_3,a_4)(-1,a_4)(-1,a_3)\\
&=(a_1,a_2)(-a_3,a_4)(-1,a_3).
\end{align*}

So now, doesn't it mean $(a_3,a_3)=(-1,a_3)=(-1,-1)$? I'm so confused how this can work. Can anyone help me out?

(Just to be clear, I don't want to see the proof of the theorem itself; as I mentioned, I managed to prove it myself. I just want to follow Serre's proof.)

Comment: I think it's a misprint: Serre should have $(-a_3,-a_4)$ not $(-a_3,a_4)$.

Comment: I recommend Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms for this material. More detail, tables of the Hilbert symbol. Also inexpensive.